# Top sales making product for each year

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables with following schema.

```
CREATE TABLE Product (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(64) UNIQUE,
  unit_price VARCHAR(6),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Sale (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  product_id INT, created_at DATETIME,
  units INT, PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES Product(id)
);

INSERT INTO Product(name, unit_price)
VALUES
('Methadone', 30),
('Codeine', 20),
('Morphine', 40),
('Fentanyl', 10);


INSERT INTO Sale(product_id, created_at, units)
VALUES
(1, '2004-01-06 08:27:25', 8),
(4, '2004-03-05 05:21:15', 24),
(2, '2005-01-06 08:26:55', 3),
(4, '2005-03-31 01:55:25', 6),
(1, '2005-11-09 11:33:20', 2),
(4, '2006-02-15 10:46:30', 4),
(3, '2006-04-14 07:40:50', 1),
(4, '2008-01-06 08:27:25', 5),
(4, '2008-01-10 21:31:45', 3),
(1, '2008-01-28 16:07:30', 9),
(3, '2008-03-05 05:21:00', 4),
(2, '2008-03-08 18:25:50', 5),
(4, '2008-05-02 02:15:20', 1),
(4, '2008-05-05 15:19:40', 3),
(4, '2008-06-28 23:08:55', 2),
(4, '2008-07-02 12:14:00', 2),
(3, '2008-08-29 09:07:50', 1),
(2, '2008-10-22 16:56:20', 5),
(3, '2008-10-26 06:01:25', 2),
(4, '2008-12-19 13:49:55', 4),
(2, '2008-12-23 02:55:30', 4),
(1, '2009-02-15 10:43:45', 4),
(2, '2009-04-14 07:37:50', 6),
(3, '2009-06-11 04:31:25', 3),
(4, '2009-08-08 01:25:30', 12),
(1, '2010-11-09 11:33:20', 8),
(1, '2011-01-14 10:22:35', 3),
(3, '2011-03-13 07:16:10', 3),
(4, '2011-05-10 04:10:15', 4),
(4, '2011-07-07 01:04:35', 4),
(4, '2011-09-02 21:58:10', 3),
(2, '2011-10-30 18:51:45', 3),
(1, '2011-12-27 15:45:20', 1),
(4, '2012-02-23 12:43:25', 2),
(4, '2012-04-21 09:37:30', 3),
(4, '2012-06-18 06:31:20', 1),
(2, '2012-08-15 03:25:40', 4),
(2, '2013-01-14 10:23:20', 4),
(4, '2013-02-01 05:01:35', 1),
(4, '2013-03-13 07:16:55', 1),
(4, '2013-03-31 01:55:10', 2),
(4, '2013-05-10 04:11:15', 2),
(3, '2013-05-27 22:48:45', 3),
(1, '2013-07-07 01:05:20', 3),
(2, '2013-07-24 19:42:20', 4),
(4, '2013-09-02 21:59:40', 4),
(3, '2013-09-20 16:36:10', 1),
(4, '2013-10-30 18:54:00', 2),
(4, '2013-11-17 13:29:45', 1),
(4, '2013-12-27 15:48:20', 3);
```

I want to find top sales making product for each year sorted by year in descending order along-with the total sale made for the top selling product.

I have written the following query.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM S.created_at) as year,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT P1.name
        ORDER BY P1.name
        SEPARATOR ',')as top,
        MAX(S.units*P1.unit_price) as sale

FROM Sale S
INNER JOIN Product P1 ON S.product_id=P1.id
GROUP BY year

ORDER BY year desc
```

Expected Output:

```
2013    Codeine,Fentanyl,Morphine   160
2012    Codeine 80
2011    Methadone,Morphine  120
2010    Methadone   240
2009    Codeine,Fentanyl,Methadone,Morphine 120
2008    Codeine,Morphine    280
2006    Fentanyl,Morphine   40
2005    Codeine,Fentanyl,Methadone  60
2004    Fentanyl,Methadone  240
```

Original Output:

```
2013    Codeine,Fentanyl,Methadone,Morphine 120
2012    Codeine,Fentanyl    80
2011    Codeine,Fentanyl,Methadone,Morphine 120
2010    Methadone   240
2009    Codeine,Fentanyl,Methadone,Morphine 120
2008    Codeine,Fentanyl,Methadone,Morphine 270
2006    Fentanyl,Morphine   40
2005    Codeine,Fentanyl,Methadone  60
2004    Fentanyl,Methadone  240
```

The query was supposed to return only the top selling products, bu it's returning all the products. Could anyone provide any help?

Comment: can you share some sample data? Adding insert statements to your question would be helpful

Comment: @Standin.Wolf I have added the sample data. please check

Comment: I love codeine, but we need data for BOTH tables!?!

Comment: @Strawberry I have added sample data for both the tables. Please check.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @GMB, MySQL 5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a variant of my [Scalar-Aggregate Comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807854/get-other-columns-that-correspond-with-max-value-of-one-column/58697900#58697900) query technique that will achieve what you want in a vastly better-performing query than self-joining the aggregate results.  As you can see below, this only ever performs a single join, then 3 cascaded layers of aggregation to achieve the final output.

```
SELECT
    yr,
    SUBSTRING(MAX(CONCAT(LPAD(total_sales, 16, '0'), products)), 17) AS best_seller,
    MAX(total_sales) AS sales_amount
FROM (
    SELECT
        yr,
        total_sales,
        GROUP_CONCAT(name order by name) AS products
    FROM (
        SELECT
            YEAR(s.created_at) AS yr,
            p.id,
            p.name,
            SUM(s.units * p.unit_price) AS total_sales
        FROM Product AS p
        INNER JOIN Sale AS s on s.product_id = p.id
        GROUP BY YEAR(s.created_at), p.id
    ) AS pys
    GROUP BY yr, total_sales
) AS py
GROUP BY yr
ORDER BY yr DESC;
```

Here's a DB Fiddle demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=e14ed7f396738ce064f1998bdb4310ac

Comment: Hi @Steven Moseley, thanks for the solution. It's also giving the same result.

Comment: Thanks @Steven Moseley, I have accepted the answer after adding "order by" in GROUP_CONCAT()

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution for MySQL < 8.0. First, aggregate sales by year and product and filter on the top selling products with an aggregate, correlated subquery; then, aggregate by year:

```
select
    year_at,
    group_concat(name order by name) products,
    total_sales
from (
    select
        year(s.created_at) year_at,
        p.name,
        sum(s.units * p.unit_price) total_sales
    from Product p
    inner join Sale s on s.product_id = p.id
    group by year_at, p.id, p.name      
    having total_sales = (
        select sum(s1.units * p1.unit_price) total_sales1
        from Product p1
        inner join Sale s1 on s1.product_id = p1.id
        where year(s1.created_at) = year_at
        group by s1.product_id
        order by total_sales1 desc
        limit 1
    )
) t
group by year_at, total_sales
order by year_at desc
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=885bbc20959530c75a667bf97bf182ed)**:

```
year_at | products                            | total_sales
------: | :---------------------------------- | ----------:
   2013 | Codeine,Fentanyl,Morphine           |         160
   2012 | Codeine                             |          80
   2011 | Methadone,Morphine                  |         120
   2010 | Methadone                           |         240
   2009 | Codeine,Fentanyl,Methadone,Morphine |         120
   2008 | Codeine,Morphine                    |         280
   2006 | Fentanyl,Morphine                   |          40
   2005 | Codeine,Fentanyl,Methadone          |          60
   2004 | Fentanyl,Methadone                  |         240
```

Comment: Yes, I was looking for this. Thank you so much @GMB.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be after this...

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a.name) names,a.total, a.year
  FROM 
     ( SELECT p.name 
            , SUM(p.unit_price*s.units) total
            , YEAR(created_at) year 
         FROM product p 
         JOIN sale s 
           ON s.product_id = p.id 
        GROUP 
           BY year
            , name
     ) a
  JOIN
     ( SELECT MAX(total) total
      , year 
   FROM 
      ( SELECT p.name 
             , SUM(p.unit_price*s.units) total
             , YEAR(created_at) year 
          FROM product p 
          JOIN sale s 
            ON s.product_id = p.id 
         GROUP 
            BY year
             , name
      ) n
  GROUP 
     BY year) b
    ON b.year = a.year AND b.total = a.total
  GROUP BY a.total, a.year
  ORDER BY year DESC;
+-------------------------------------+-------+------+
| names                               | total | year |
+-------------------------------------+-------+------+
| Fentanyl,Codeine,Morphine           |   160 | 2013 |
| Codeine                             |    80 | 2012 |
| Morphine,Methadone                  |   120 | 2011 |
| Methadone                           |   240 | 2010 |
| Morphine,Methadone,Fentanyl,Codeine |   120 | 2009 |
| Morphine,Codeine                    |   280 | 2008 |
| Morphine,Fentanyl                   |    40 | 2006 |
| Codeine,Methadone,Fentanyl          |    60 | 2005 |
| Methadone,Fentanyl                  |   240 | 2004 |
+-------------------------------------+-------+------+
```

Comment: This does produce the expected results as well.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Select name, year(created_at), sum(unit_price*units ) 
from Product p inner join sale s on p.id = s.product_id 
group by name, year(created_at)
order by 2, 3 desc
```

Comment: Have edited my question. Could you please check again?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the top selling product for each year, use `rank()` and an aggregation query:

```
select ps.*
from (select p.name, year(s.created_at) as year, sum(p.unit_price*s.units) as sales
             rank() over (partition by year(s.created_at) order by sum(p.unit_price*s.units) desc as seqnum
      from Product p inner join
           sale s
           on p.id = s.product_id 
      group by name, year
     ) ps
where seqnum <= 1;  -- You can change "1" for more rows
```