# Sql query max/min only on the highest group

Tags: sql

How can we achieve in getting the max and min values that is group by group.

eg query, `select country,max(size) from tablename group by country`, this will query each max values of a group column

data output is ->

```
country  |  size
myr      |  456
usd      |  123
eur      |  909
```

expected output should only show the max size which is 909 from eur

```
country  |  size
eur      |  909
```

Comment: `select max(size) from yourtablename` and get your output. do not add group and you will get result

Comment: @Ajay2707 , this will only return the max value of the size whereby the usecase im looking should return both country and maxvalue

Comment: order by max size desc take first  row. `LIMIT 1`,  `Top(1)`, .. depending on your DBMS.

Comment: probably `select * from table order by size desc limit 1` or even `select *, max(size) from df`

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function -

```
select country, size from 
(select country, size, row_number() over (order by size desc) rn from mytable) rs 
where rs.rn=1
```

You did not mention DB so i assumed most popular DB syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Please check

```
Declare @t table(country varchar(50),  size int)
insert into @t values ( 'myr', 456),('usd',123),('eur', 909)


select t.* from @t t
join
( select max(size) as id from @t) maxval
on t.size = maxval.id
```

see this answer: [SQL Query to get column values that correspond with MAX value of another column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807854/sql-query-to-get-column-values-that-correspond-with-max-value-of-another-column)

Answer (score 0):

For SQLite, MySQL v5.6 you can simply use:

```sql
SELECT country, MAX(size) FROM tablename
```

For MS-SQL you can use `TOP()`:

```sql
SELECT TOP(1) country, size FROM tablename 
ORDER BY size DESC
```

For PostgreSQL, MySQL v5.7+ you can use `LIMIT`:

```sql
SELECT country, size FROM tablename 
ORDER BY size DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: @adnansharif better?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to get the row having the max size. So, you can order the table by `Size` in descending order. then pick the top row of it. So, you may use the following query.

```
SELECT Country, Size
FROM tableName
ORDER BY Size DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Also, you can tweak the above query if you **really** want to use `Group By` in your query, use the following-

```
SELECT Country, MAX(Size) AS Size
FROM tableName
GROUP BY Country
ORDER BY Size DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```