# How do I select all columns that belong to one columns MAX() value in SQL?

Tags: sql, max

I need to get values from different columns (in one record) where one column has a maximum value. How do I select the maximum value of one column **and** all the other columns from the same record?

```
SELECT MAX(bid_price) 
FROM oc_product_auctionpack_customers pauc 
LEFT JOIN oc_product_auctionpack pau ON (pauc.bid_product_id = pau.product_id) 
WHERE bid_product_id = '" . $product_id . "'
```

This only selects the highest value of the selected column

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using (MSSQL, MySQL, Oracle, Postgres, etc)? You are wide open for SQL Injection, use parameterized/prepared statements and don't concatenate the query string with user inputs directly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Query to get column values that correspond with MAX value of another column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807854/sql-query-to-get-column-values-that-correspond-with-max-value-of-another-column)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can't comment on other posters answers yet since my reputation isn't high enough, Himanshu's answer is definitely more robust. I'd add that you can use RANK() instead of ROW_NUMBER() in the event that you have two max bid prices that are the same.

---

You should probably be able to use group by -

```
SELECT MAX(bid_price) 
var_1,
var_2,
var_3
FROM oc_product_auctionpack_customers pauc 
LEFT JOIN oc_product_auctionpack pau ON (pauc.bid_product_id = pau.product_id) 
WHERE bid_product_id = '" . $product_id . "'
GROUP BY var_1, var_2, var_3;
```

The values brought in by var_1, var_2, var_3 would be distinct relative to the max value.

Unless you mean you want one record, you could do the same with the following additions -

```
SELECT MAX(bid_price) 
var_1,
var_2,
var_3
FROM oc_product_auctionpack_customers pauc 
LEFT JOIN oc_product_auctionpack pau ON (pauc.bid_product_id = pau.product_id) 
WHERE bid_product_id = '" . $product_id . "'
GROUP BY var_1, var_2, var_3
ORDER BY MAX(bid_price) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

This should return only the single highest record.

Comment: Thanks! I edited my question, yes I need only the single highest record (one record only). Looks like I need to `SELECT (MAX(bid_price) customer_id, ... ... ...` if I need to get the `customer_id` column value that corresponds the record with the highest `bid_price` column value. Is that it?

Comment: Yes, that would do it, I edited my response slightly as well, Himanshu's answer won't require you to add a var_x for every new item you want to bring in. If you have multiple of the same high bid_price and you want all to display you could swap row_number() for rank() in the partition. Rank would assign the value 1 to all records with the high bid_price using bid_price desc

Comment: Ahh, totally clear. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Try using `row_number()`

```
Select * from (
SELECT pauc.*, pau.*, row_number() over (order by
bid_price desc) rn 
FROM oc_product_auctionpack_customers pauc 
LEFT JOIN oc_product_auctionpack pau ON (pauc.bid_product_id = pau.product_id) 
WHERE bid_product_id = '" . $product_id . "') 
Where rn=1;
```