# Group By with Max Date and another column

Tags: mysql

I have the following table.

| id | user_id | file_id | completed | updated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 161 | 10 | 1 | 2022-10-11 |
| 2 | 164 | 11 | 1 | 2022-10-12 |
| 3 | 161 | 10 | 1 | 2022-10-12 |
| 4 | 167 | 10 | 1 | 2022-10-10 |
| 5 | 167 | 10 | 1 | 2022-10-11 |
| 6 | 167 | 10 | 1 | 2022-10-12 |

I want to select the row for each user having the max `updated` date for each `file_id`.

```
SELECT * FROM user_file
WHERE updated = (SELECT uf.updated FROM user_file uf GROUP BY uf.user_id,uf.file_id)
```

I have come up with this query but it returns an error "Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807854/sql-query-to-get-column-values-that-correspond-with-max-value-of-another-column?rq=1

Comment: First, you're missing the MAX around the subquery, Secondly, you are basically selecting all users with a certain updated date. There may be many, that can never be the only selection criteria: select all users with this updated date. You want to have a specific link with the group by of the subquery. Look up JOIN's.

Comment: But I can not use ID to join tables because the ID is just an auto incrementing integer. `user_id` and `file_id` are the ones that does matter

Comment: So join on those fields. It is quite simple but based on the limited info I have about your situation I would say: do not go into query designing before educating yourself thoroughly on the basics of relational databases. It is essential you get the basics first, especially the basics on joining tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to check these out?

- [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)
- [Retrieving the last record in each group - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Personally prefer the window function solution

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM (SELECT id, user_id, file_id, ...
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY file_id ORDER BY updated DESC) ranked_order
          FROM user_file) a
 WHERE a.ranked_order = 1
```